# background image not showing on div

Tags: html, css

My background-image is not showing on my div element. Background-color works just fine, but using an image doesn't show.

```css
.scifititle {
 width: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 1080px;
 left: 350px;
}

.scifibg {
 background-image: url(images/stars.gif);
 margin-top: 1200px;
 width: 1280;
 height: 276px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scifibg">
    <img class="scifititle" src="images/sci-fi-title.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Check if bg image is reachable (images/stars.gif), if images is inside root of your app: try with background-image: url(/images/stars.gif) or background-image: url(../images/stars.gif) or simirlar.

Comment: Yes! I was forgetting to add the ../ since the image was outside of the CSS folder. What a rookie! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your Background image not showing - maybe the image location is wrong. I checked your CSS code, I think you did some wrong CSS.
Please try this HTML & CSS code. I hope it will help you perfactly.

```
<div class="scifibg">
    <img class="scifititle" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/p4M1mK1Lbtc2tt54b6JUQUJ5U8RcwHnEAPH7_87X2NH9Rc8N9ek0Xm2BUq_wmLuOWXlylcDlZFOg4xF3aQtwsyF9frOHoqiQdWVpG-v4VO-Jb_4lIQ" alt="Google Map Mark Icon">
</div>

.scifibg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 100px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/31/00/ec/3100ecd92a583cb03dec1f7be1fa0924.png);
} 
.scifititle {
  max-width: 570px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Your solution isn't clear. It appears that you've published an image to a hosting service, but you make no mention of that. Please see [answer].